# Are strictly stable minimal surfaces area minimizing?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a strictly stable minimal surface. Can we show that $\Sigma$ is in fact strictly area minimizing amongst surfaces that are close in a certain topology? (say $W^{2,2}$ for instance) It seems to me that this should be the case but I cannot find any proof of this statement. More generally, does the same conclusion hold true for a strictly stable critical point of a functional 
$$
\Sigma \mapsto \int_\Sigma f(x,A,\nabla A,\dots)d\mu
$$
where $f$ is a smooth function and $A$ the second fundamental form of $\Sigma$?

Perhaps this is a bit of a stupid question, I just get stuck at the following point: if we have a small perturbation $\Sigma_t$ then it is clear that 
$|\Sigma_t|>|\Sigma|$ for some small $t\in(0,\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon$ depends on the perturbation. In a finite dimensional problem we could use compactness and be done, however how can we proceed in an infinite dimensional problem?

Comment: What does strictly stable mean?

Comment: That the first eigenvalue of the Jacoby-Operator is positive, or more generally for a functional $J$, $\partial^2 J(v,v) \geq c |v|$, where $\partial ^2$ is the second variation and $|\cdot|$ is a suitable norm of the vector space in which we consider the perturbations.